# Network Drivers for DH67BL motherboard with i7 Intel processor

Tags: 10.04, drivers

I have an issue while installing motherboard software for DH67BL.

In ubuntu it's not connecting to the network and unable to find the suitable drivers for the ubuntu server version. Any help or guidance in this regard will be helpful. Are there any rpm or deb files available for this version of the motherboard that I can download?

Comment: Was this question migrated here because it contains the word "server"? I would rather see it on SU... DH67BL is µATX, not a MP mobo.

Comment: It should really be on askubuntu ...

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)